# Range slider Plotly : How not to add a line

Tags: python, plotly, rangeslider

I have the code below, that produce a subplot with a unique range slider. Except i want the range slider to be on row 2, not to create a replicated row2, is there a way to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.subplots as sp
from datetime import datetime



data1 = [
    [1, datetime(2022, 11, 26)],
    [7, datetime(2022, 11, 29)],
    [4, datetime(2022, 11, 30)],
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=["value", "date"])


data2 = [
    ["unique_row","a", datetime(2022, 11, 26),datetime(2022, 11, 27)],
    ["unique_row","b", datetime(2022, 11, 27),datetime(2022, 11, 30)],
    ["unique_row","c", datetime(2022, 11, 30),datetime(2022, 12, 2)],
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=["unique_row","value", "dates_begin","date_end"])


fig1= px.line(df1, x="date", y="value")
fig2 = px.timeline(df2, x_start="dates_begin", x_end="date_end", y="unique_row",         color="value")

fig_sub = sp.make_subplots(rows=2, 
                          shared_xaxes=True)

fig_sub.append_trace(fig1['data'][0], row=1, col=1)
fig_sub.append_trace(fig2['data'][0], row=2, col=1)

fig_sub.update_layout(xaxis2_rangeslider_visible=True)
```

Comment: Can the current output graph be shared?

Comment: can you explain the desired output a bit further? the `rangeslider` is connected to `fig2`, so if we remove fig2 from `fig_sub`, then what is the purpose of the rangeslider?